# Mapping arbtrary object values to function inputs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object of arbitrary functions and a function that takes a method name and an object or an array with parameters and then selects and calls the function accordingly. The problem is that functions have a variable number of inputs and some of them contain optional fields with default values and I can't find a general way to map inputs of the parameters to inputs of the function.

One way to solve the problem when the arguments come in the form of the array is just simply called the function with the `...` operator: `func(...args)`, but that still leaves me with a problem, because I can't use these methods on objects. Is there any way to map object values to function inputs by using object keys?

Abstract example of the situation:

```
const funcs = {
 func1: (arg1, arg2, arg3 = 'something') => .....does something
 func2: () => ....does something
 func3: (anotherArg1) => ...does something

}


function callFunction(method: string, args: unknown[]| object) {

if (Array.isArray(args)) {
 return funcs[method](...args)
}

else (if args instanceof Object) {
 //... Here I need to parse the args and call the function in "funcs" object.
}

}
```

Comment: I wish this code were a [mcve] instead of pseudocode; I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do.  There's no principled way to observe the names of function parameters from the outside; those are essentially local variables to the function body and considered implementation details.  That is, the functions `foo => 123` and `bar => 123` are the same thing, and the names `"foo"` and `"bar"` cannot be seen from something that wants to call those functions.  If that wrecks your plan, then we can probably stop.  If not, could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, maybe with a [mcve]?

Comment: Can we reduce this to just a single function and being able to call it with either an object or an array?  If so, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKkbKW) approach what you're trying to do?  Since parameter names are unobservable from outside, the only way to do this is if you give an array of object keys you want to correspond to parameters, as shown in the playground link here.

Answer (score 0):

Just spread the second argument of `callFunction(method, ...args)`

```js
const funcs = {
  func1: (arg1, arg2, arg3 = 'something') => {
    [arg1, arg2, arg3].forEach((a, i) => console.log(`arg${i+1}:`, JSON.stringify(a)));
  }
}

function callFunction(method, ...args) {
  return funcs[method](...args)
}

const method = 'func1';
callFunction(method, [1, 2], {foo: 'bar'})
```

Comment: I think the OP really means `args: unknown[] | object`, not `...args` - @jcalz' comment is spot on.